# OpenGL using multiple shaders

Tags: opengl, shader

I am trying to add a second shader to an OpenGL project I am working on. It is the most basic shader that just outputs a color for testing purposes, it compiles and it runs but it seems to do nothing, everything that is drawn with the other shader is there. However if I leave an intentional error in the shader it draws with white in the right places.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on? Can I get a basic example of using multiple shaders?

I've being doing research on the subject and I can't quite get the purpose of `glBindFragDataLocation` , both my shaders are currently bound to location 0. Also I am using the default fraebuffer, can that be the source of the problem?

Comment: Impossible to answer with so little details. Post relevant parts of your code - how you compile shaders, link them into program and use them for drawing.

Comment: glBindFragDataLocation just determines where the result of a user-defined varying (in the fragment shader) is writen to. They map to the values specified by glDrawBuffers.